# Cocoapods pod file install not working "Unable to find a specification for `RealmSwift (~> 0.97)`" swift

Tags: swift, cocoapods, realm

I'm attempting to install Realm for swift, expect terminal keeps giving me this error:  `Unable to find a specification for RealmSwift (~> 0.97)`. My pod file has been laid out exactly as they recommend. This is my pod file:

```
target 'AppName' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 0.97'

end

target 'AppName Tests' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 0.97'

end

target 'AppName UITests' do

end

target 'AppName Keyboatd' do

end

target 'AppName Keyboard' do

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it with Realm Objective-C and it worked fine for me. That's strange.

It's possible that since the version is actually called '0.97.0', maybe it's necessary to include that extra '.0'.

Alternatively, is it completely necessary to include the version specifier in there? You can just leave it off, and you'll still get the latest version of Realm (0.97.1 was released a few days ago!)